# CentOS 8 NFS - showmount hangs

Tags: centos, rhel, nfs

I have NFS server running on Rhel 7.7 and trying to mount from CentOS 8..

Mounting itself works fine, i can mount it and it works, but when i try just to search for shared folders by `showmount -e` it just hangs and doesn't show anything. I can't even determinate the showmount process with Ctrl+C, or D...

I found here, that it is maybe problem with kernel version higher that 4.17 (i have 4.18), but i did not find any solution how to fix it..

Is there any other way how can i see shared folders by nfs?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to post more info, such as your NFS exports configuration and your mount configuration. Post the relevant log from `/var/log/messages` and systemctl logs for NFS. There is a similar issue that is caused by firewall https://superuser.com/questions/1331231/terminal-hangs-when-mounting-doing-showmount