# How to prevent showmount from hanging?

Tags: centos, nfs

We are implementing a web front end to manage NFS and CIFS shared folders. One part displays the available share points (exports) available from any arbitrary IP address.

The backend uses `smbclient -L <ip> -U <user>` to query SMB/CIFS shares and uses `showmount -e <ip>` to query NFS shares.

However, `showmount` hangs if target server is running any kind of firewall (doesn't matter Windows, Mac, or Linux).  (These SE/SU posts [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1331231/terminal-hangs-when-mounting-doing-showmount) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544559/centos-8-nfs-showmount-hangs) mention that NFS has issues with firewalls)

We tested show mount to both existing and non-existing machines. Testing several combinations of `showmount -e <ip>`:

```
Machine NFSD     Firewall   Result
Exists  Stopped  Off        clnt_create: RPC: Unable to receive
Exists  Stopped  On         HANGS
Exists  Running  On         HANGS
Exists  Running  Off        returns list of exports
None    n/a      n/a        clnt_create: RPC: Unable to receive
```

When `showmount` hangs, it can only be killed by `SIGKILL` (-9).  We tried using [`timeout`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) to give up after a time period but it also hangs.

Running `strace` from another terminal shows it gets stuck on `connect`

```
$ strace -p 63552
strace: Process 63552 attached
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(111), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.2.10")}, 16
```

**Question** In this scenario, how can we use `showmount` without it hanging?

One idea is to write a program to first try open a connection to the NFS IP:port and, if successful, then run `showmount`.  But is there any other way?

Backend running on Centos 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timeout` command can be instructed to use the `SIGKILL` signal (see `man timeout`). This works with `showmount` quite effectively:

```
timeout --signal KILL 3s showmount -e remoteNFSServer
```